# Suppress warning messages about downloaded executables in custom installer

Tags: .net, windows, installation, warnings

We are writing a custom installer for our software. This installer will execute several other installer that are either transferred over the network or on a usb disk. When executing these in their own process we get Windows warnings that these installers might not be safe. Is there a way to suppress this type of messages?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what APIs you are using, the file may get an alternate data stream that indicates the "zone" the file came from.  Depending on what zone it is and on the security settings on your machine, you may be prompted to allow the file to execute.  I don't know where or if this is officially documented, but the name of the alternate data stream is "Zone.Identifier"; I'm sure a Google search would find interesting things.  I think it would be enough to simply delete the alternate data stream before executing the file.

Answer (score 0):

The point of these warning messages is to avoid accidentally executing software from an untrusted source.

If there is a way to circumvent these dialogs, don't you think malware programmers would use them already?

In your case, since you're already executing on the behalf of the user, copy the files onto the local disk and execute them from there, that should work.